# GWT Junit TestCase

Tags: java, gwt, junit, testcase

i want to test a RPC with GWT Junit. I use the standard GWT example and create the following testcase:

```
public class TestGreetingService extends GWTTestCase {
/**
 * Must refer to a valid module that sources this class.
 */
public String getModuleName() {
    return "com.TestGreeting";
}   

/**
 * This test will send a request to the server using the greetServer method
 * in GreetingService and verify the response.
 */
public void testGreetingService() {
    // Create the service that we will test.
    GreetingServiceAsync greetingService = GWT
            .create(GreetingService.class);
    ServiceDefTarget target = (ServiceDefTarget) greetingService;
    target.setServiceEntryPoint(GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "TestGreeting/greet");

    // Since RPC calls are asynchronous, we will need to wait for a response
    // after this test method returns. This line tells the test runner to
    // wait
    // up to 10 seconds before timing out.
    delayTestFinish(20000);

    // Send a request to the server.
    greetingService.greetServer("GWT User", new AsyncCallback<String>() {
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
            // The request resulted in an unexpected error.
            fail("Request failure: " + caught.getMessage());
        }

        public void onSuccess(String result) {
            // Verify that the response is correct.
            assertTrue(result.startsWith("Hello, GWT User!"));

            // Now that we have received a response, we need to tell the
            // test runner
            // that the test is complete. You must call finishTest() after
            // an
            // asynchronous test finishes successfully, or the test will
            // time out.
            finishTest();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Unfortunately i get the following error: Can someone help me? I also upload the project: goo.gl/UnFyt

```
 [WARN] 404 - POST /com.TestGreeting.JUnit/TestGreeting/greet (192.168.1XX.XX) 1427 bytes <br>
Request headers <br>
Host: 192.168.1XX.XX:53577 <br>
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.19) Gecko/2010031422 <br> Firefox/3.0.19 <br>
Accept-Language: en-us <br>
Accept: */* <br>
Connection: Keep-Alive <br>
Referer: http://192.168.1XX.XX:53577/com.Test...8.1XX.XX:53572 <br>
X-GWT-Permutation: HostedMode <br>
X-GWT-Module-Base: http://192.168.1XX.XX:53577/com.TestGreeting.JUnit/ <br>
Content-Type: text/x-gwt-rpc; charset=utf-8 <br>
Content-Length: 181 <br>
Response headers <br>
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1 <br>
Content-Length: 1427 <br>
```

Answer (score 1):

You get a 404 warning, your service can't be found.
There must be something wrong with your ServiceEntryPoint definition.

Try the @RemoteServiceRelativePath("greet") annotation for your synchronous interface or correct your setServiceEntryPoint to

```
    target.setServiceEntryPoint(GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "greet");
```

Also take a look at the DevGuide, the instructions there helped me very well with getting used to the GWT RPC service:
https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/2.4/DevGuideServerCommunication#DevGuideImplementingServices

Comment: Thank you! I had to add " <servlet path="/greet" class="com.server.GreetingServiceImpl" />" in the gwt.xml